# How to show one by one Page using TKinter and change Page by Next button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a newbie, testing out Tkinter.

I want to create 2 pages and there is a button to move from page 1 to page 2.

However, my code shows up 2 pages at the same time (1 in the back and 1 in the front), and the `Next` button just pop the next page to the front and the current page to the back :(

Below is my code:

```
root = tk.Tk(className = 'Python Examples - Window 0')
root.geometry("600x700")
root.resizable(0,0)

root1 = tk.Tk(className = 'Python Examples - Window 1')
root1.geometry("600x700")
root1.resizable(0,0)

next_button = tk.Button(root, text= 'Next', height =1 , width=5, command= root1.lift)
next_button.place(x=30, y =600)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function that is called when the button is pressed. In this way, you only create the second window when called and not since the beginning.

```
def second_window(root):
    root1 = tk.Tk(className = 'Python Examples - Window 1')
    root1.geometry("600x700")
    root1.resizable(0,0)
    root.withdraw()

root = tk.Tk(className = 'Python Examples - Window 0')
root.geometry("600x700")
root.resizable(0,0)

next_button = tk.Button(root, text= 'Next', height =1 , width=5, command=lambda: second_window(root))
next_button.place(x=30, y =600)
```

Comment: Hey, it's working, However, Is there anyway to hide the first page because when the second page shows up, the first page is simply sent into the back

Comment: You can call the function withdraw on the first window. I have modified my answer accordingly.